# Android Studio. White spaces into canvas.drawText are normalized

Tags: android, canvas, whitespace, spaces, drawtext

In Studio (Android) I use Canvas to drawText, like the following:

```
    String apuestas = "Hola       que tal?";
    canvas.drawText(apuestas, 100, 210, paint);
```

The result text in the canvas has all spaces between "hola" and "que" normalized, only one space is remaining. I want to draw all de white spaces inside the String. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

in order to make this happens you should use `_paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE)`

My own worked with the following combination:

```
_paint.setLetterSpacing(0.1f);
_paint.setTextScaleX(0.9f);
_paint.setAntiAlias(true);
_paint.setLinearText(true);
_paint.setSubpixelText(true);
_paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```